# Regex How to match everything after last occurance, but not including the matched character

Tags: php, regex

I have a string, for example:

```
black-guitar-12-strings-7584
```

And I am trying to match the set of digits at the end (not always 4 in length).

So far I have:

```
(-)[^-]*$
```

Which matches the last part but I don't want to include the last hyphen also.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: Is there a case where this can't be solved by grouping? `-([^-]*)$` and save the first group.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this pattern: `\d+$` or `[0-9]+$`. It matches last sequence of digits.

Answer (score 4):

Just omitting it would work: `[^-]+$`

For more complex issues then this one you could also look at [lookahead / lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), but those aren't necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match everything after the last "-", this will do it:

```
[^-]*$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d+)$
```

should work. if you have more than just digits, you could use something like

```
-(.+?)$
```

I added capturing because I assume that's what you want. it uses a non-greedy quantifier, which will match the minimum.

Comment: Why non-greedy in the first example?